# Kotlinter gradle accept trailing commas in .editorconfig file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, editorconfig

I want to use the Kotlinter ([GitHub](https://github.com/jeremymailen/kotlinter-gradle#configuration)) plugin in my Kotlin project for formatting and linting.
So now when I run the formatting task, it cuts off all my trailing commas in e.g. Enums or something similar.

Before formatting:

```
enum class TypeEnum(val value: String) {
TYP1("TYP1"),
TYP2("TYP2"),
TYP3("TYP3"),
}
```

After formatting:

```
enum class TypeEnum(val value: String) {
TYP1("TYP1"),
TYP2("TYP2"),
TYP3("TYP3")
}
```

Trailing commas are also a Best Practice (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#trailing-commas) and I want to use them.

So I tried to set up a **.editorconfig** file like in the [documentation](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/#editorconfig) in the root of my project to overwrite the settings of Kotlinter. Here's my file:

```
root = true

[{*.kt,*.kts}]
ij_kotlin_allow_trailing_comma = true
ij_kotlin_allow_trailing_comma_on_call_site = true
```

It seems like these lines have no effect on the formatting of Kotliner. So what er correct settings in .editorconfig to allow trailing commas?
Here is a [description](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/rules/standard/#trailing-comma-on-call-site) of the rules for Kotliner but I didn't get it so set them correctly.

Thanks for your help!